# How to avoid NextJs triggers getServerSideProps once it already has triggered once?

Tags: next.js

I'm using dynamic routes with catch-all option [...slug]. Normally the URL is whether  "mywebsite.com/[username] " or "mywebsite.com/[username]/[postid]".

Then in getServerSideProps({ query }) I receive an Array with [username] or both [username] and [postid]. I use just the username slug info to fetch all username data.

After that, based on how many elements a received from { query } I will decide if:

1 - I will render de user home page Component,
2 - or the post page component (in case a receive both [username] and [postid]

So far, everything works fine. But, when browsing pos page and userhome page, even using  component, NextJS triggers getServerSideProps all the time, what is not desire since it should be a SPA.

**How to avoid it, since I already have all the necessary fetched data?**

Here is my folder structure:

Pages
index.js (Just a welcome page)
[...slug].js

Components
UserHomePage.js
PostPage.js

Here is my code in [...slug].js

```
import Router from 'next/router'
import UserHomePage from '../components/UserHomePage'
import PostPage from '../components/PostPage'

const HomePage = ({ data, slug }) => {

  if (slug.length === 1) return <UserHomePage data={data}/>
  
  if (slug.length > 1) return <PostPage data={data} slug={slug}/>
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  const { slug } = query;

  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/account/${slug[0]}`);
  const data = await res.json()

  return {
    props: {
      data,
      slug,
    }
  }
}

export default HomePage
```

Here is the code in UserHomePage

```
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function UserHomePage({ data }) {
  const { posts, account } = data;

return (
  <>
  {posts.map(post => (
    <div>
      <Link href={`/${account.username}/[...slug]/`} as={`/${account.username}/${post._id}/`}>
      <a>
      {post._id}
      </a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  ))}
  </>
)
}
```

And here is my code in PostPage

```
import Router from 'next/router'

export default function PostPage({ data, slug }) {
  const post = data.post.filter(post => post._id.toString() === slug[1])
  return (
  <>
  <h1>Produto - {post[0]._id}</h1>
    <button type='button' onClick={() => Router.back()}>Back</button>
  </>
  )
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: How have you determined that `getServerSideProps` runs every time? By design while client will send an API request, its the result of the `getServerSideProps` running. 
> https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#technical-details-2

Comment: Hi Remakay. getServerSideProps is called automatically when teh page [...slug].js is open. I'm going through this right https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing. It maybe a solution.

I will update it here if I figured it out

Comment: Add a cookie value, check for it and then ignore that logic if the cookie value is set